# Visual Studio 2015 (C++): lock search word (ctrl+F) for all .cpp/.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

If I press Ctrl+F in B.cpp, a search box will appear on top-right of the editor.

I enter a word - let's say "Account" - in the search box.
I find the result, as I wished.

Then, I want to search "Account" in another file, C.cpp.

I click at the top bar to navigate to C.cpp -> the search box disappear. (No!)

If I press Ctrl+F again, the word that appeared in the search box is not "Account" anymore, but change to a word that text editor's cursor is pointing/focusing to.  (No!)

- How to prevent disappearance of the search box?
- How to lock the search word to be the same?

The issue is destroying my productivity and my mind.

Comment: Ctrl F is context dependant.  When you click somewhere else, the context changes.  Try typing the word in the search box in the toolbar and then clicking on the search button to the left of the box.

Comment: @cup   "Search box in the toolbar", the toolbar that appear when I press ctrl+shift+F ?   That panel is big, not so convenient as the tiny ctrl+F box.

Comment: After finding the first item, you can close the panel and press F3 for find next

Comment: Thank, cup!  F3 is quite convenient.  (1) is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+F is a "Quick-Find" and it depends of the context.

Use instead the "Find in Files" command (Ctrl+Shift+F) and select "Current Document" in the "look in" options.

Now if you change file, and type again ctrl+shif+F the search options remains as you want.

Alternately you can disable the option "Automatically populate Find What with text from the editor" in Tools>Options>Enviroment->Find and replace but of course now you have to paste the word you want to find.

Comment: That bar is so big, even after I try to shrink.    It can do the job, but it is not very convenient.  Thank.

Comment: Check the answer edit, you can disable the "Automatically populate Find What with text from the editor" so also quick-find will not reset the searched word, but now you have to do a step more (ctrl+F and paste or digit the word you want to search)

Comment: Wow, that solve (2).  The word remains the same, as I wish.  The first issue still remain, but cup provided a way to solve it.    Thank!